# Flink ProcessWindowFunction behavior on keyed stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a keyed stream with a tumbling window whose size is 60 seconds.

For example, there are 10 keys in total named from key_1 to key_10.
Consider a situation:
Within a certain window 12:00:00 to 12:01:00, I have data fallen in this window with key being key_1 to key_9; There is no key_10 data in this min.

When the window gets fired, ProcessWindowFunction gets called and starts its work.
I wonder how the window function works, and I have two guess:

1. The function will calculate for each key no matter there is data or not (in this case, key_1 to key_10)
2. The function will only be called and process those keyed streams with data (in this case, key_1 to key_9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows are created lazily when events are assigned to them. So there will be no window for key_10 for that interval during which key_10 has no events.

There being no window for key_10, the `ProcessWindowFunction` will not be called, and you won't get any results for key_10 for that particular timeframe.

This is covered in the documentation in the section on [surprises with the window API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/streaming_analytics/#surprises) under [no results for empty TimeWindows](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/streaming_analytics/#no-results-for-empty-timewindows).